# How to render python dictionary values in Javascript Fetch API (forEach)?

Tags: javascript, python, django, dictionary, fetch

I am trying to render python dictionary values inside a Javascript Fetch API. I tried various ways to do so such as serializing values and using dictionary keys to access the dictionary values. I got no error message but the values I rendered are all "undefined" on my webpage.

Python

```
def portfolio_position(request):
positions = Portfolio.objects.filter(owner=request.user, off_portfolio=False).order_by('-symbol').values()
return JsonResponse([position for position in positions], safe=False)
```

Javascript

```
function load_portfolio_position() {
  fetch('/portfolio_position')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(positions => {
      console.log(positions);
      var table = document.getElementById("portfolio-table");
      positions.forEach(position => {
        var row = table.insertRow(1);
        row.id = `row_${position.symbol}`;
        var symbol = row.insertCell(0);
        var price = row.insertCell(1);
        var change = row.insertCell(2);
        var average_cost = row.insertCell(3);
        var position = row.insertCell(4);
        var pnl = row.insertCell(5);
        var pnl_percent = row.insertCell(6);
        symbol.innerHTML = `${position.symbol}`; 
        price.innerHTML = `${position.price}`; 
        change.innerHTML = `${position.change}`; 
        var avc = parseFloat(position.cost).toFixed(3);
        average_cost.innerHTML = `${avc}`; 
        position.innerHTML = `${position.position}`;
        pnl.innerHTML = `${position.pnl}`;
        pnl_percent.innerHTML = `${position.pnl_percent}`;
      });
  })
}
```

[image: This is the dictionary with values from console log]

[image: This is the undefined result I got in my webpage]

Appreciate your help!

Comment: `symbol.innerHTML = \`${position.symbol}\`;` is nonsense; just do `symbol.innerHTML = position.symbol;`.

Comment: Can you share your HTML

Comment: This took way too long. You have `var position = row.insertCell(4);` which overwrites the `position` variable

Comment: Use this instead: https://jsfiddle.net/c2jvwt6n/

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you! This is what I am looking for!